# RDFazer show no results ( syntax error in the query )

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology, virtuoso

it's my first time working on ontology.
I downloaded Virtuoso, also the [RDFazer](https://github.com/Rahien/RDFazer) which helps me to find the matches terms with [ESCO](http://data.europa.eu/esco/model) ontology ..
this is the default sitting JSON file ( including the query statment), i did not change it at all:

```
{
"sparql": "http://localhost:8890/sparql",
"fileURI": "",
"profile": "ESCO (virtuoso)",
"profiles": {
    "ESCO (virtuoso)": {
        "query": "select ?target ?label (group_concat(distinct(?labels); separator=\"| \") as ?altLabels) (group_concat(distinct(?types); separator=\"| \") as ?types)\n where { \n{ ?target a <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/model#Occupation> . } \nUNION\n { ?target a <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/model#Skill> . } \n?target <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#prefLabel> ?thing3. ?thing3 <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#literalForm> ?label .\n ?target <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> ?types .\n{ ?target <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#prefLabel> ?thing1. \n?thing1 <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#literalForm> ?plabels . \nFILTER (bif:contains(?plabels,\"'$searchTerm*'\")) . \nFILTER (lang(?plabels) = \"en\") . } \nUNION\n { ?target <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#altLabel> ?thing2.\n ?thing2 <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#literalForm> ?plabels .\n FILTER (bif:contains(?plabels,\"'$searchTerm*'\")) . \nFILTER (lang(?plabels)= \"en\") . \n} \nOPTIONAL {?target <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#altLabel> ?thing4\n. ?thing4 <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#literalForm> ?labels\n. FILTER (lang (?labels) = \"en\") \n}\nFILTER (lang (?label) = \"en\") \n} GROUP BY ?target ?label",
        "uriToUrl": "'https://ec.europa.eu/esco/web/guest/concept/-/concept/thing/en/' +uri",
        "labelProperty": "label",
        "labelPredicate": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel",
        "storedInfo": {
            "label": {
                "predicate": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel",
                "type": "property",
                "decorate": {
                    "xml:lang": "en"
                }
            },
            "altLabels": {
                "predicate": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#altLabel",
                "type": "property",
                "csv": "|",
                "decorate": {
                    "xml:lang": "en"
                }
            },
            "types": {
                "predicate": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type",
                "type": "relation",
                "csv": "|"
            }
        }
    },
    "default (skos)": {
        "query": "select ?target ?label (group_concat(distinct(?labels); separator=\"| \") as ?altLabels)\n (group_concat(distinct(?types); separator=\"| \") as ?types) where {\n ?target <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core##prefLabel> ?label .\n ?target <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> ?types .\n{ ?target <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> ?plabels .\n FILTER (bif:contains(?plabels,\"'$searchTerm*'\")) . }\n UNION {\n ?target <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#altLabel> ?plabels .\n FILTER (bif:contains(?plabels,\"'$searchTerm*'\")) .\n } OPTIONAL {\n?target <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#altLabel> ?labels.\n FILTER (lang (?labels) = \"en\") }\nFILTER (lang (?label) = \"en\") \n} GROUP BY ?target ?label",
        "uriToUrl": "uri",
        "labelProperty": "label",
        "labelPredicate": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel",
        "storedInfo": {
            "label": {
                "predicate": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel",
                "type": "property",
                "decorate": {
                    "xml:lang": "en"
                }
            },
            "altLabels": {
                "predicate": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#altLabel",
                "type": "property",
                "csv": "|",
                "decorate": {
                    "xml:lang": "en"
                }
            },
            "types": {
                "predicate": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type",
                "type": "relation",
                "csv": "|"
            }
        }
    },
    "ESCO (pure SPARQL 1.1)": {
        "query": "select ?target ?label (group_concat(distinct(?labels); separator=\"| \") as ?altLabels) (group_concat(distinct(?ttypes); separator=\"| \") as ?types)\nwhere { \n{ ?target a <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/model#Occupation> . } \nUNION\n{ ?target a <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/model#Skill> . } \n?target <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#prefLabel> ?thing3. ?thing3 <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#literalForm> ?label .\n?target <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> ?ttypes .\n{ ?target <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#prefLabel> ?thing1. \n?thing1 <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#literalForm> ?plabels . \n} UNION\n{ ?target <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#altLabel> ?thing2.\n?thing2 <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#literalForm> ?plabels .\n} \nFILTER (regex(?plabels,\".*$searchTerm.*\",\"i\")) . \nFILTER (lang(?plabels) = \"en\") . \nOPTIONAL {?target <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#altLabel> ?thing4\n. ?thing4 <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#literalForm> ?labels\n. FILTER (lang (?labels) = \"en\") \n}\nFILTER (lang (?label) = \"en\") \n} GROUP BY ?target ?label",
        "uriToUrl": "'https://ec.europa.eu/esco/web/guest/concept/-/concept/thing/en/' +uri",
        "labelProperty": "label",
        "labelPredicate": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel",
        "storedInfo": {
            "label": {
                "predicate": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel",
                "type": "property",
                "decorate": {
                    "xml:lang": "en"
                }
            },
            "altLabels": {
                "predicate": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#altLabel",
                "type": "property",
                "csv": "|",
                "decorate": {
                    "xml:lang": "en"
                }
            },
            "types": {
                "predicate": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type",
                "type": "relation",
                "csv": "|"
            }
        }
    },
    "ESCO (fuseki, text index)": {
        "query": "select ?target ?label (group_concat(distinct(?labels); separator=\"| \") as ?altLabels) (group_concat(distinct(?ttypes); separator=\"| \") as ?types)\nwhere { \n{ ?target a <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/model#Occupation> . } \nUNION\n{ ?target a <http://ec.europa.eu/esco/model#Skill> . } \n?target <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#prefLabel> ?thing3. ?thing3 <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#literalForm> ?label .\n?target <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> ?ttypes .\n?target <http://jena.apache.org/text#query> \"$searchTerm\". \nOPTIONAL {?target <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#altLabel> ?thing4\n. ?thing4 <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#literalForm> ?labels\n. FILTER (lang (?labels) = \"en\") \n}\nFILTER (lang (?label) = \"en\") \n} GROUP BY ?target ?label",
        "uriToUrl": "'https://ec.europa.eu/esco/web/guest/concept/-/concept/thing/en/' +uri",
        "labelProperty": "label",
        "labelPredicate": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel",
        "storedInfo": {
            "label": {
                "predicate": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel",
                "type": "property",
                "decorate": {
                    "xml:lang": "en"
                }
            },
            "altLabels": {
                "predicate": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#altLabel",
                "type": "property",
                "csv": "|",
                "decorate": {
                    "xml:lang": "en"
                }
            },
            "types": {
                "predicate": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type",
                "type": "relation",
                "csv": "|"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I tried to query many times. I did not now it says syntax error as shown in this image ( sorry I could not copy the error, i was only able to take a screenshot)

[image]
is there any way that I can fix this error ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: First thought is that you may be running an older version of Virtuoso that doesn't support SPARQL 1.1, and thus doesn't support `group_concat` in this location. You can check the version with `virtuoso-t -?` or [a SPARQL query](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtCheckSvrVersionViaSparql).

Comment: Your SPARQL query is not correct. Looks like all URIs `<...>` are skipped, and you have "couple" patterns instead of triple patterns.

Comment: The SPARQL query reported in the error message does not match what's in the code snippet. As @StanislavKralin says, the angle-bracket-wrapped URIs are missing. I cannot quickly think of a reason why this might be, given your described interaction, so maybe you can provide more detail of the steps you've taken? You might also try testing SPARQL queries directly through the HTTP-based `/sparql` endpoint, to try to narrow down where issues lie/arise.

Comment: thank you for your responses. As I knew the RDFazer is google chrome plugin. I do not think that I need to change anything as shown in documentation ( https://github.com/Rahien/RDFazer) the ESCO includes list of skills terms ( skills such as c++ , programming languages, .. etc ) and this tool matches and shows any term that is in the web page with the ESCO.  I updated the virtuoso to newer version as @TallTed mentioned and the error is gone. but still no results shown I do not know why.

Comment: That RDFazer page says, it "is for tagging a website with RDFa concepts" and "is currently a WIP and should only be used if you know what you are doing." I wonder if you wouldn't be better off with some other tools for early projects? What are you trying to do? (Probably a new question would be a better place to dig into this...)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to update apparently old Virtuoso to a current version.